# chrome extension - TypeError: Error in invocation of declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I'm trying to remove a single rule from dynamic rules of `declarativeNetRequest` of chrome with this code:

```js
const unblockHost = (clickData) => {
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
        removeRuleIds: bannedHosts.map( (h, i) => {
            if( new URL(clickData.pageUrl).hostname === h ){ 
                console.log(h, i, i + 1)
                return i + 1
            }
        })
    });
}
```

I have an empty array named `bannedHosts` that will be filled with all the rules added to chrome using this function

```js
const initRulesList = () => {
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules( (rules) => {
        rules.forEach( (r) => {
            bannedHosts.push(r.condition.urlFilter)
        })
        console.log(bannedHosts)
    })
}
```

When I call the function to remove the a banned host I will get this error message

```js
Error in event handler: TypeError: Error in invocation of declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(declarativeNetRequest.UpdateRuleOptions options, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'options': Error at property 'removeRuleIds': Error at index 0: Invalid type: expected integer, found undefined.
```

How I can fix it to be able to add and remove rules dynamically in my extension?
How many dynamic rules I can handle with this chrome api?

Comment: Some of the elements returned by `map` are undefined. Filter them out: `.map(fn).filter(Boolean)`. Also don't call updateDynamicRules if the result is an empty array.

Comment: At the moment I'm writing I have just one host added to the rules. What I need is to remove a specific host and I think map function isn't the best solution?